# Error When Deserializing a JSON String to a Java Object with Interface Data Member

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON String and I want to deserialize it to a Java object with a interface data member.  The Java object looks like this:

```
public class Person {
     private String id;
     private String name;
     private AddressInterface addr;
}
```

Both the Person and the AddressInterface are third party classes, so I can't make any changes to them.

When I used the following to deserialize the JSON string,

```
 objectMapper.readValue(json_file, Person.class)
```

I got the following exception.  It's because the object mapper doesn't know how to deserialize the AddressInterface  field.  Can someone let me know how to deserialize the string into an Person object in this case?  Many Thanks.

```
 abstract types either need to be mapped to 
 concrete types, have custom deserializer, 
 or be instantiated with additional type information
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance

Comment: You have not implemented proper deserialization into your AddressInterface.java can you share the code file to get more detail about problem.

Comment: The interface is abstract since it can not know the type implementing the interface. You could add a field for the class name of the interface and add a custom deserialize which would retrieve the correct class to use.

Comment: @Locke  Thanks but I can't make any changes to the interface or the Person class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddressInterface` is an interface and is considered abstract. Both classes `Foo` and `Bar` could implement `AddressInterface`, but it would be unable to tell which one the data should be deserialized as.

### Random idea which *might* work:

Put the interface in a wrapper. I'm just guessing since I don't know the library context, but maybe something like this. Also there's probably a few typos in here, but it shows the general idea.

```java
    public class AbstractSerializable<T> implements Deserialize {
        private final String className;
        private T obj;

        public AbstractSerializable(T obj) {
              this.obj = obj;
              this.className = obj.getClass().getCardinalName();
        }

        @Override
        public AbstractSerializable deserialize(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
             String clazz = input.readNext(String.class);
             return objectMapper.readNext(Class.forName(clazz));
        }

    }
```

**Edit:** This would probably break if you tried to put a lambda in it.

**Edit 2:** @Hadi Note is correct that Gson would make some things easier, however it would run into the same issues. I did find [this article](https://technology.finra.org/code/serialize-deserialize-interfaces-in-java.html) which explains how to fix it when using Gson. It uses a similar approach to my answer, but they have a much better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

With **GSON** library you can get rid of the boilerplate codes!

You can use GSON library in the link below!

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gson/gson_quick_guide.htm

Comment: Gson might already have a built in solution to this problem, but my initial reaction is that it would run into the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is deserializing AddressInterface property because its an interface and I think objectMapper is trying to initilaize it's default constructer like bellow

```
addr = new AddressInterface();
```

you can create an empty concrete class which inherits the AddressInterface and use it instead of AddressInterface

```
public class Adress implements AddressInterface {
...
}


public class Person {
 private String id;
 private String name;
 private Adress addr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I can't change the Person class.  It's out of my control.

Comment: what about creating your own Person class ?